# How to click on elements returned from page.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How can I click on elements returned from `page.evaluate`?

```js
const allCategoryElements = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const allElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".mySelector")];

  return allElements.filter((element) => {
    const ul = element.querySelector("ul");
    return !ul || !ul.children.length;
  });
});

for (const categoryHandle of allCategoryElements) {
  await categoryHandle.click(); // ERROR: categoryHandle has no click method
}
```

Basically, what I want is an array of elements that I can then click on (OUTSIDE OF THE EVALUATE). Elements need to be of type ElementHandle, if I'm correct.

Answer (score 2):

elements can't be returned using `page.evaluate` as they're not serializable. Use `page.evaluateHandle` instead.

From the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args)

> The only difference between page.evaluate and page.evaluateHandle is that page.evaluateHandle returns in-page object (JSHandle)

example:

Here the element is not returned.

```js
const element = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('a'));
```

while here the element will be an instance of JSHandle:

```js
const element = await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.querySelector('a'));
```

You can use [`jsHandle.asElement()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#jshandleaselement) to get the ElementHandle.

Comment: could you be a bit more explicit? An example for my case would be helpful. Take into consideration that I need to click on the resulting elements

Comment: @RolandJegorov added more detail

Comment: This is not correct. .evaluate can return Element and it does in my example. Documentation -`If the function passed to the page.evaluate returns a non-Serializable value, then page.evaluate resolves to undefined`. Which it didn't. Instead I get `Element[]`. My question requires the return to be an array of elements that I can then call click on.

Comment: @RolandJegorov you can simply test your hypothesis that puppeteer doc is incorrect using a minimum working example (which I provided here) on any website, observe the result, and maybe correct your statement. Since you haven't provided the website, I'm not able to reproduce your result and verify your statement.

Answer (score 0):

To work with all element, You need to use [page.evaluate](https://pptr.dev/) function and evaluateHandle together

```
// Get the "viewport" of the page, as reported by the page.
const jsHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
const allElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".mySelector")];
  return allElements.filter((element) => {
    const ul = element.querySelector("ul");
    return !ul || !ul.children.length;
  });
 });
 await page.evaluate(all => {
  for (const elm of all) {
       elm.click();
     }
  } , jsHandle);
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Especially since you just copy pasted my code. Is this a mistake?

Comment: Typo  sorry.. Why writing i did typo